# Possible to show a loading window when datagridview is filled with data?

Tags: c#, datagridview

My app consists of 3 tabs, each tab has a DGV, tab 1 and 2 do not contain that much data within the DGV but in tab 3 it can be between 100-5000 rows

The problem im having is that when i start my app, and move to tab 3 it takes a while before anything is displayed..

Im looking for a way to display a loading form to the user while the data is being added to the DGV..

How would i accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Start loading data on a background thread and monitor the progress(displayed as progress bar).If you are doing it on main thread than you'll hang your interface.

[Theres one good article but it is in VB.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318604)

Answer (score 1):

Long running operations should be running in a seperate worker thread, commonly [BackgroundWorker](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CE4QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx&ei=MVYuUOPWOsnlyAGg2IG4Dw&usg=AFQjCNFwLYOqQ7vrjVJ7SroICXQH-GDyEQ) class.  This prevents the UI from locking up during said operation.  You can also choose to display a loading dialogue while this thread runs.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are correct. But since you specifically asked about a loading window, I remembered a very nice example in [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14841/How-to-write-a-loading-circle-animation-in-NET).

In a project I was involved with, we took this example and made it independent. We added static methods called Start and Stop, and the Start method would create a thread, and then load the window, while the Stop method signaled the form it needs to close gracefully.

Hope this helps!